# Non existence of stable vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^4$ with $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The Horrocks–Mumford  bundle is the only known rank 2 vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^4$ which is not split.

My question is:

How to prove that there is no  a rank 2 stable  vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^4$ with Chern classes $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$?

Answer (score 8):

Let $\mathrm{E}$ be a vector bundle of rank $2$ with $c_1(\mathrm{E})=0$ on $\mathbf{P}^4$. Then the Chern character of $\mathrm{E}$ can be written as
$$\mathrm{ch}(\mathrm{E})=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^m}{(2m)!}c_2(\mathrm{E})^m=2-c_2+\frac{1}{12}c_2^2+\ldots.$$
The degree $4$ part of the Todd class of $\mathbf{P}^4$ is $35h^2/12$,
and the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem says that the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $\mathrm{E}$ is
$$\chi(\mathrm{E})=2\chi(\mathrm{O}_{\mathbf{P}^4})+\frac{1}{12}\int_{\mathbf{P}^4} \big(-35c_2 h^2+c_2^2).$$
Integrality requires that (identifying Chern classes with integers) $-35 c_2+c_2^2$ is divisible by $12$; in other words, that $c_2+c_2^2$ is divisible by $12$. In particular, there are no such $\mathrm{E}$ with $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$ or $2$. The case $c_2=3$ was ruled out by Barth and Elencwajg; the latter is known to frequent this site, no doubt he has much more to say.

Schwarzenberger noticed that the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem imposes divisibility constraints on the Chern classes, and what I explain above is merely a special case. For rank $2$ bundles on $\mathbf{P}^3$ you get the (probably most known) constraint that $c_1 c_2$ must be even. You can use this to show that $\mathrm{T}_{\mathbf{P}^2}$ cannot be the restriction of a rank $2$ bundle $\mathrm{E}$ on $\mathbf{P}^3$.

(A comprehensive discussion of such questions can be found in the standard reference `Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces' by Okonek-Schneider-Spindler.)

Comment: What exactly does this condition mean? The expression $c_2(c_2 + 1 - 3c_1 - 2c_1^2)$ has terms in degrees 4, 6, and 8.

Comment: I am a novice here, but it seems that since these chern casses are on projective space, they can be written as integer multiples of powers of the hyperplane class, and the c's here are those integers.  At  least that is what  I get from appendix I, Thm. 22.4.1, pp. 165-166, of Hirzebruch, Topological methods in algebraic geometry.  For this reason Schwarzenberger himself writes them with the letter d.

Comment: Dear @Simpleton , Thank you very much for your answer. All the best.

Comment: @MCjr I hope the updated version is more useful! Roy Smith's interpretation is spot-on.

Comment: @Simpleton Yes, your updated version is very useful! Thank you!